# Is "however" used correctly in "However, Life is not that easy cake..."?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

This is my basic sentence :

> .... They try to make his life better.
>       However, Life is not that easy cake which turns to what we want...

My research shows that I can do  :

Using ‘however’ to mean ‘in whatever manner’, ‘by whatever means’ or
‘to whatever extent’

**Is it really my case here ?**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61530/discussion-between-towfik-alrazihi-and-jay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't your case here. In your sentence "**however**" means "**nevertheless**" ([**Grammar-monster**](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/starting_a_sentence_with_however.htm)):

> When **however** means **nevertheless**, it is followed with a comma. When **however** means **to whatever extent**, there is no comma after it. For example:
>
> - I like oats. However, I cannot eat flapjacks. *(nevertheless)*
> - I like oats. However much I try, I cannot eat flapjacks. *(to whatever extent)*

Comment: Here's more information: [**QuickAndDirtyTips.Com**](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/starting-a-sentence-with-however-right-or-wrong)